# MS Access 2016. How to assign an MS Access desktop icon as the application icon also

Tags: ms-access

Fact:  A desktop icon can be changed for a link to a database.

- edit Properties
- Change Icon...
- Look for icons in this file:  %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Root\VFS\Windows\Installer{90160000-000F-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\accicons.exe

Fact: The user can assign a database icon to the current database

- From MS Access 2016 select "File" from the ribbon
- Select "Options"
- Select "current database" from the left panel
- At the Application Icon:  select browse.

Question: What path do I use to find the same icon as the desktop icon?

Comment: you need to extract the icon from the exe, save it, use by Access

Comment: e.g. with IrfanView.

Comment: Question: What path?  What file/

Comment: the file from your step `At the Application Icon: select browse. `

Comment: You simply use the SAME path for the desktop shortcut icon as the SAME one you specified in the access application. One has to presume that the Access application will reside in some folder. In that folder is the icon specified for Access, and you use the same path to the icon for the desktop shortcut. When you do this, the application icon will even show in the task bar. So both your Access applicaton can specify a path name to ico file and so can the windows shortcut also use that ico file.

Comment: Thanks gentlemen.  I was able to find an Access file to use.  Using IrfanView I opened the file and saved the image as an icon.  The image quality was kind of poor, and the image was saved as an opaque rectangle that failed to allow the background colors of the taskbar to silhouette the icon.